# Pragmatically changing url DJnativeswing

Tags: java, swing, browser, compiler-errors, djnativeswing

Im using DJ native swing to make a web browser. After my browser gathers certain information I would like it to change to another website.

Does anyone know how to do this? I've tried:

```
package chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.demo.examples.webbrowser;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import chrriis.common.UIUtils;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface;
import chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JWebBrowser;

/**
 * @author Christopher Deckers
 */
public class SimpleWebBrowserExample extends JPanel {

  public SimpleWebBrowserExample() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    webBrowserPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Native Web Browser component"));
    final JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
    webBrowser.navigate("http://www.google.com");
    webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(webBrowserPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // Create an additional bar allowing to show/hide the menu bar of the web browser.
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 4, 4));
    JCheckBox menuBarCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Menu Bar", webBrowser.isMenuBarVisible());
    menuBarCheckBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        webBrowser.setMenuBarVisible(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
      }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(menuBarCheckBox);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }

  /* Standard main method to try that test as a standalone application. */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    UIUtils.setPreferredLookAndFeel();
    NativeInterface.open();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DJ Native Swing Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new SimpleWebBrowserExample(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
    NativeInterface.runEventPump();
  }

}
```

I'd like to change the webpage from outside of

`public static JComponent createContent() {...}`

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example). 2)  Always copy/paste error & exception output. -- My 'best guess' would be that it is out of scope by that point.  ..But I don't like guessing.

Comment: I added all the code.. I just fiddled with it to put the webBrowser.navigate("https://www.yahoo.com"); in a reachable area, but its in a messy loop which never lets the contentPane start... but that's kinda what I want to do (if it worked.)

Comment: *"I added all the code.."*  Why?  I suggested you post a MCTaRE.

Comment: Forgive me, I added a link to the minimal code, its complete, and tested, and readable. I just want the program to change the page after a minute for example (without user interaction).

Comment: When I wrote *"..post a MCTaRE"*  I did not mean "post a link to a MCTaRE".  I meant *"..post a MCTaRE as an **edit to the question**"*

Comment: ok.. I copied the script and added it to the page...

Comment: Yes, as I guessed in my first comment.  The `webBrowser` is out of scope by that point.  Really.. these types of newbie problems should be figured out in command line apps.  Leave GUI programming aside for a (long) while.